# Analog of STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION in Gson

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I want to prevent so "json injection" when deserialize JSON data.
By default json parsers don't care a lot about duplicated keys in an object and just overwrite them.

I spend some time to find a feature reversing this behavior. 
I succeed with Jackson, but not in Gson.
The problem is that a lot of code is based on Gson in the project.
So switching to Jackson is not easy.

In Jackson this feature called "STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION"

```
{"x": true, "x": false}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort of.
For some reason, Gson detects name collisions while deserializing `Map` instances, but does not do such a check for data bags or `JsonElement` and its descendants (therefore you cannot write a tree-based JSON deserializer to detect them).

Given,

```
{
    "x": true,
    "x": false
}
```

```java
final class Foo {

    @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryBoxing")
    final boolean x = Boolean.valueOf(false);

}
```

```java
final Foo foo = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Foo.class);
if ( !foo.x ) {
    throw new AssertionError();
}
```

This fails for the standard `JsonReader`.
However, you can work around that at the lowest level.
It's a bit tricky and not well-optimized but covers all possible deserializers (and this probably explains why Gson behaves differently in different deserializers: every such a deserializer should do this check itself and can merely miss the job).

```java
final class StrictNamesJsonReader
        extends JsonReader {

    private final Stack<Set<String>> nameStack = new Stack<>();

    private Set<String> names;

    private StrictNamesJsonReader(final Reader reader) {
        super(reader);
    }

    static JsonReader of(final Reader reader) {
        return new StrictNamesJsonReader(reader);
    }

    @Override
    public void beginObject()
            throws IOException {
        super.beginObject();
        names = new HashSet<>();
        nameStack.add(names);
    }

    @Override
    public String nextName()
            throws IOException {
        final String name = super.nextName();
        if ( !names.add(name) ) {
            throw new JsonSyntaxException("Detected duplicate property name " + name + " in " + names + " at " + this);
        }
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void endObject()
            throws IOException {
        super.endObject();
        nameStack.pop();
        names = !nameStack.isEmpty() ? nameStack.peek() : null;
    }

}
```

As you can see, this `JsonReader` implementation manages names duplicates detection itself and throws something like the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Detected duplicate property name x in [x] at StrictNamesJsonReader at line 3 column 5 path $.x
```

if duplicates detected.

You can ask for revising your question at https://github.com/google/gson/pull/649 though.
I do believe deserializers are a wrong way of detecting duplicates, and `JsonReader` should be enhanced unlike what's suggested in that PR.